# Css side menu disappear when size changed on mobile safari

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, mobile-safari

I have strange problem. I made a side menu in css and javascript to show a shopping cart on the side of a page but when content of the cart div changed it disappear from screen.

I made a jsfiddle to isolate the code for the question but problem: I can't reproduce the bug with the jsfiddle version and I can't find why I have this bug.

Here is the jsfiddle to understand the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/dragouf/mqVmC/35/

```
// when click show side panel
    $('#' + prefix + '-btn').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('open');

        // Hide all other boxes
        var boxes = $('.box-container');
        $.each(boxes, function (index, box) {
            if ($(box).data('prefix') != prefix)
                hideBoxes($(box).data('prefix'), true);
        });
        var right = $('#' + prefix + '-container').css('right');
        var width = $('.' + prefix + '-box').outerWidth();
        var rightHide = '-' + width.toString() + 'px';

        var zindex = 180;
        if (right != '0px') {
            rightHide = '0px';
            zindex = 1000;
            $('#cart-container').css('z-index', zindex);
        }

        $('#' + prefix + '-container').stop(true, true).animate({ right: rightHide }, 800, function () {
            // Animation complete.
            $('#cart-container').css('z-index', zindex);
        });

        return false;
    });

    // hide after loading
    hideBoxes(prefix, false);

    // recalculate when div resized
    $('.' + prefix + '-container').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function () {
        if (window[prefix + 'width'] != $(this).width())
            hideBoxes(prefix, false);

        window[prefix + 'width'] = $(this).width();
        window[prefix + 'height'] = $(this).height(); // pas utiilise pour le moment
    });

    // recalculate when window resize
    $(window).resize(function () {
        hideBoxes(prefix, false);
    });

    // Follow window scroll
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 80) {
            //$('#' + prefix + '-container').animate({ top: (defaultTop - 80) }, 200);
            $('#' + prefix + '-container').css('top', (defaultTop - 80) + 'px');
        } else {
            $('#' + prefix + '-container').stop(true, true).css('top', defaultTop + 'px');
        }
    });
}
```

And here the website where I have this bug:

http://goo.gl/UWrIHy

To reproduce it just go to this url in mobile safari (ipad or iphone), add an item to the cart (first time you add an item it will disappear<--bug) and reload the page. Each time it will finish to reload the cart from the server the cart menu will disappear...

If anyone understand this bug I would be very thankful

Comment: Could you tell us a little more about the site? I see it is built on Bootstrap3? Is it built on Wordpress? Is this a plugin?

Comment: no it's all hand made and yes its based on bootstrap 3 and knockoutjs like I precised it on the tags.